# How to append to xml table with java?

Tags: java, xml, append

Okay so I'm creating a users class which asks for input then stores it in an XML file using java. I figured out to create the original XML file I think but I'm have trouble figuring out how to add a new user with the attribute "id" of one more then the previous User entry.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
/*imports */

    public class CreateUser {   
        static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

/* object names*/
    String name;
    String age;
    String bday;
    String gender;
    String location;
    String orientation;
    String relationship;
    String hobbies;
    String choice;
    String username;
    String password;

    public void makeUser(){

/*left out code to get user entries here 

seemed irrelevant/*

    /*checks for file if it doesn't exist then it creates it else it should append
 the user to the xml document with a id increase of one.
 The appending part I'm not sure how to do.*/
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml");
            if(f.exists()) { 
                try {
                    /* need help here*/
                }
            }
            else{
                try{
                    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document users = docBuilder.newDocument();

                    Element user = users.createElement("user");
                    users.appendChild(user);

                    Attr attr = users.createAttribute("id");
                    attr.setValue("0");
                    user.setAttributeNode(attr);

                    Element dname = users.createElement("name");
                    dname.appendChild(users.createTextNode(name));
                    user.appendChild(dname);

                    Element dgender = users.createElement("gender");
                    dgender.appendChild(users.createTextNode(gender));
                    user.appendChild(dgender);

                    Element dlocation = users.createElement("location");
                    dlocation.appendChild(users.createTextNode(location);
                    user.appendChild(dlocation);

                    Element dorientation = users.createElement("orientation");
                    dorientation.appendChild(users.createTextNode(orientation));
                    user.appendChild(dorientation);

                    Element drelationship = users.createElement("relationship");
                    drelationship.appendChild(users.createTextNode(relationship));
                    drelationship.appendChild(drelationship);


                    Element dhobbies = users.createElement("hobbies");
                    dhobbies.appendChild(users.createTextNode(hobbies));
                    dhobbies.appendChild(dhobbies);

                    Element dchoice = users.createElement("choice");
                    dchoice.appendChild(users.createTextNode(choice));
                    dchoice.appendChild(dchoice);

                    Element dusername = users.createElement("username");
                    dusername.appendChild(users.createTextNode(username));
                    dusername.appendChild(dusername);

                    Element dpassword = users.createElement("password");
                    dpassword.appendChild(users.createTextNode(password));
                    dpassword.appendChild(dpassword);

                    Element dbday = users.createElement("birthday");
                    dbday.appendChild(users.createTextNode(bday));
                    dbday.appendChild(dbday);

                    Element dage = users.createElement("age");
                    dage.appendChild(users.createTextNode(age));
                    dage.appendChild(dage);

                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(users);
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml"));

                    StreamResult test = new StreamResult(System.out);
                    transformer.transform(source, result);
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                    pce.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
                    tfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

I know its a lot of code to look through and I don't want an exact coded answer but maybe just how to append the user with the attribute value one more then the previous entry. Or a point in a the direction of a helpful website. Anything really I've been perplexed for a little and I feel like I should get something this simple. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please, give short example how it would look, your XML. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first section(`if` block), I think you can open your file in append mode as below to add an `user`, **assuming `user` node is not wrapped in another node.**

```
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
    new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml", true));
```

There are two changes in above statement:

1. Using `FileWriter` in place of `File`
2. Using a second parameter `true`, which open the file in `append` mode.

**EDIT**: To get the max existing ID, you need to read file and look for ID tag as below:

```
  File xmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("userId");//use the id tag name
  int maxId = 0;
  for(Node node: nList){
      if(Integer.parseInt(node.getTextContent()) > maxId ){
        maxId = Integer.parseInt(node.getTextContent());
      }
  }
  int newId = maxId +1; //use this ID
  xmlFile.close();//close the file
```

Comment: So the first If is just to check if the file already exists in which case it would append the new user to the XML file, else it creates the XML file. Could I do result.exists() with it as a stream result? should I not just create the streamresult object in the Try{ } for the append?

Comment: @user1371330 I missed that part. If you want to always append the user if the file exist then have only one section and open the file in append mode. If the file wasn't there, it will create it otherwise it will append.

Comment: So I would just need to change
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml")); 
to a FileWriter in the second part and remove the if statement altogether? Also do you have any idea how to get the id attribute to be one more then the previously entered users id attribute? Thanks a lot! You've already been really helpful.

Comment: @user1371330 Remove your `if-else` and change the StreamResult as `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
    new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Steven\\Workspace\\twitter\\src\\users.xml", true));`

Comment: That solved the appending issues! thanks a ton. Now my only problem is making the id attribute have a value of one more then the previous one. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1371330: For that, you need to read the file. Use the opposite process to digest your `xml` and search for max ID (You can simple get all ID nodes and look for max value among them).

Comment: Your awesome man thanks a ton. I don't know why this perplexed me so. I hope you have some good karma coming your way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider JAXB, here is a working example to start with:

```
static class Users {
    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.user = users;
    }
}

static class User {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("user1");
    Users users = new Users();
    users.setUsers(Arrays.asList(user));

    JAXB.marshal(users, new File("users.xml"));

    users = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("users.xml"), Users.class);
    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setName("user2");
    users.getUsers().add(user2);

    JAXB.marshal(users, System.out);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider SAX, unlike DOM it's fast and has no size limit. Here's a basic example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xml = "<users><user><name>user1</name></user></users>";
    XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {
        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equals("users")) {
                addUser();
            }
            super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        }

        private void addUser() throws SAXException {
            super.startElement("", "", "user", null);
            addFileld("name", "user2");
            super.endElement("", "", "user");
        }

        private void addFileld(String name, String value) throws SAXException {
            super.startElement("", "", name, null);
            super.characters(value.toCharArray(), 0, value.length());
            super.endElement("", "", name);
        }
    };
    Source src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    Result res = new StreamResult(System.out);
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, res);
}
```

output:

```
   <users><user><name>user1</name></user><user><name>user2</name></user></users>
```